# SAPUI5 Not clearing view after browser back button pressed

Tags: sapui5

I have a 2 page app..

First time into the 2nd page, it performs the onInit() and works fine.

If the browser back button is hit and the 2nd page is entered into again onRouteMatched() is no triggered, the view is not cleared and this causes issues in that elements of the view are duplicated etc.

I've tried a number of things: 
- Clearing the view model, 
- Destroying the page on Exit, 
- Duplicating onInit into onRouteMatched.

but nothing seems to work.

Reloading fixes the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a hash changer. I'll throw up some code if you need it.

Comment: I tried the route of capturing the back arrow event and destroying the page,  but when re-entering the app, the elements of the page (from the view.xml) aren't re-instantiated.

Comment: Yea, destroying it ain't going to work because it will just stay destroyed. Can you throw up the code of your onInit and onRouteMatched methods.

Comment: onInit: function () {
   this.sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("rsa-action-plan/rsa-action-plan") + "/";

   // Setup Routing and view Model.
   var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
   oRouter.getRoute("actionplan").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
   this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(this.oViewModelData), "view");
  },

  _onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
   var self = this;
   window.onhashchange = function () {
    if (window.innerDocClick) {
    } else {
     if (window.location.hash === '') {
      location.reload();
     } 
    }}

Comment: Sorry about the formatting

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but the following code does reload the page and resolve the issue....

Comment: window.onhashchange = function () {
    if (window.innerDocClick) {
    } else {
     if (window.location.hash === '') {
      location.reload();
     } 
    }
   }

Comment: This redirects back to the previous page and performs the reload, not great visually but I can work at it.

Answer (score 0):

`onInit()` is only called once when the view is instantiated. It is generally used to  modify the View before it is displayed, bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.

`.attachMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this)` will trigger when the route is matched on re-navigating to that view.

For example you would have this in the `onInit()` section:

```
    this.getRouter()
        .getRoute(<views-route-name-here>)
        .attachMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);
```

**EDIT**

I see you did post some code in the comments section:
Makes sure your route name is "actionplan" in your manifest.json and that this is appearing after the hash. This should ensure a match and trigger the `_onRouteMatched` function in your case.

If this doesn't solve it can you expose your manifest.json.